# Проблема с функцией, возвращающей список

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа, python-2.x

Функция должна возвращать список размером `le`, состоящий из случайно заполненных символов функции `special`, но она возвращает только один случайный символ вместо положенного количества `le`.
Код:

```
def special():
    return(random.choice(['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','{','}','[',']']))

le=int(input('Enter length'))

def length(type,list):
i=0
while i<le:
    new = type
    list.append(new)
    i=i+1
    return list

a=[]
print(length(special(),a))
```

Comment: если у вас действительно такой код, а не плохое форматирование вопроса, то все верно - вы возвращаетесь из функции на первой итерации цикла while. Уберите лишний отступ в return, тогда должно выполнять все итерации

Comment: @BOPOH, скорее добавить отступы перед всем ниже `def length(type,list)` до `return list`, но тогда получится список заполненный одним и тем же случайным символом. Хотя, может так и задумано.

Comment: после def length(type,list): есть отступ, он не появился, и таки да, почему-то заполнилось всего лишь одним символом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Итерация 1: исправляем форматирование кода

```
def special():
    return(random.choice(['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','{','}','[',']']))

le=int(input('Enter length'))

def length(type,list):
    i=0
    while i<le:
        new = type
        list.append(new)
        i=i+1
    return list

a=[]
print(length(special(),a))
```

Обратите внимание, что `return list` не должен быть внутри while, иначе функция будет возвращать список из одного элемента.

Появляется другая проблема: функция генерирует список из одного и того же случайного символа. Пример: `['!', '!', '!', '!', '!']`

Причина: в функцию передается результат выполнения функции special, а по идее нужно, чтобы функция special вызывалась внутри функции length. Решение: передавать внутрь саму функцию special, а вызывать ее внутри.

## Итерация 2: передаем в функцию length саму функцию special

```
def special():
    return(random.choice(['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','{','}','[',']']))

le=int(input('Enter length'))

def length(type,list):
    i=0
    while i<le:
        new = type()
        list.append(new)
        i=i+1
    return list

a=[]
print(length(special,a))
```

Результат - функция возвращает список из случайных символов.

Теперь комментарии по стилю.

1. Вы используете имена встроенных функций Python (type, list) в качестве имен параметров. Так делать не нужно.
2. Имена функций должны описывать что они делают. Что может делать функция с именем length? Определять длину. У вас же она возвращает список. Название типа generate_list будет намного лучше.
3. Один из параметров (требуемая длина списка случайных символов) передается через глобальную переменную. Это плохая практика, лучше сразу отучаться так делать.
4. Удобнее не передавать существующий список внутрь функции, а создавать его там и возвращать через return. У вас получается, что вы и добавляете элементы в существующий список, и выводите результат через return. Так, в принципе, можно делать, но обычно не нужно.
5. Вы используете while, хотя тут удобнее использовать цикл for.

## Итерация 3: изменения в коде с учетом замечаний

```
def special():
    return(random.choice(['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','{','}','[',']']))

def generate_list(generate_element, n):
    s = []
    for i in range(n)  # для python2 xrange вместо range
        new = generate_element()
        s.append(new)
    return s

le=int(input('Enter length'))
print(generate_list(special, le))
```

Ну и пример, как функцию `generate_list` реализовать в две строки:

```
def generate_list(generate_element, n):
    return [generate_element() for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения. Не обессудьте, первая "пограмма" на питоне.

Comment: @DeepsHIT, ничего, все когда-то начинали.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Помимо уже описанной ситуации с отступами, Вам необходимо скорректировать Ваш код, а именно:

```
def special():
    return(random.choice(['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','{','}','[',']']))

le=int(input('Enter length'))

def length(type,list):
 i=0
 while i<le:
    new = type()
    list.append(new)
    i=i+1
 return list

a=[]
print(length(special ,a))
```

Обратите внимание как происходит передача special и работа с ней в length